# lookup a value from same table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table called '`Branch`'.
Type B = Branch and Type U = Unit

```
BRANCH_UNIT_ID | BRANCH_UNIT_CD | TYPE | PARENT | DESC
1                ABC              B      null     ABC_Branch
2                EEE              U      3        EEE_UNIT
3                FFF              B      null     FFF Branch
```

I have another table called '`Line`' that has the column `UNIT`.

```
LINE_ID | LINE_VALUE | UNIT
1         123456       EEE
```

I need to join these 2 tables `Line` and `Branch` to retrieve `BRANCH_UNIT_CD` if it is a Unit and lookup the corresponding `PARENT` value.

So for this example, my expected result should be

```
LINE_ID | LINE_VALUE | BRANCH_UNIT_CD | UNIT
1         123456       FFF              EEE
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this :

```
select ll.line_id, ll.line_value, bb.branch_unit_cd,ll.unit
  from 
(
select l.*, b.parent
  from line l
  left outer join Branch b
    on ( l.unit = b.branch_unit_cd )
) ll inner join
   Branch bb
 on ( ll.parent = bb.branch_unit_id );

LINE_ID LINE_VALUE  BRANCH_UNIT_CD  UNIT
------- ----------  --------------  ----
1       123456      FFF             EEE
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/AQJRH40827)

Comment: 1st line should it be `ll.*` instead of `l.*`? Getting error when im using the latter